# compiling cuda using cmake works only after calling make twice

Tags: cuda, cmake, makefile

I want to use cmake to compile CUDA with '-arch=sm_12', but cmake/make behave strangely.

I have following CMakeLists.txt:

> CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)
>
> PROJECT(test)
>
> FIND_PACKAGE(CUDA REQUIRED)
>
> CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE(test prog.cu)
>
> SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_12")
>
> SET(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS} CACHE STRING "Forced" FORCE)

but 'cmake ../src && make' leads to a executable for sm_20.
The flag seems to be ignored.

EDIT: If I call 'make' again (without any modification in CMakeListss.txt) it uses the Flag. - But only if I force the flag to cache (last line)

Am I doing anything wrong?

EDIT: After checking again: I have to call 'make' twice to work correctly. Does anybody know this behaviour?

Comment: Not verbose is changing, the flag you add / don't add changes the behavior.

Comment: Not a cmake expert, but isn't CMakeLists.txt generated by the cmake command? It looks like you're wanting to make a toolchain file with the CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS pre-set for the machine you're using. I think `cmake ../src -DCUDA_NVCC_FLAGS="-arch=sm_12" && make` is the recommended way to override the behavior.

Comment: @jefflarkin: No, not at all. CMakeLists.txt control CMake, comparable to Makefiles and make.

Comment: Please post an [mcve]

Comment: @usr1234567 My mistake, thanks for chiming in. I think I confused it with CMakeCache.txt.

Comment: Just a thought. What about if you set the flag before you add the executable?

Comment: Thanks inJeans! That helped!

Answer (score 2):

inJeans was right:

FindCUDA-docs https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/FindCUDA.html

This is the essential information:

"Note that any of these flags can be changed multiple times in the same directory before calling CUDA_ADD_EXECUTABLE, CUDA_ADD_LIBRARY, CUDA_COMPILE, CUDA_COMPILE_PTX, CUDA_COMPILE_FATBIN, CUDA_COMPILE_CUBIN or CUDA_WRAP_SRCS:"